# "Like it" button using SPServices

Tags: spservices, like

Default rating system in Sharepoint 2013 allows to like elements in list view like this:

[image]

and I have no problem to get count of "likes" with FieldRef Name='LikesCount' but I wonder if is it possible to add "Like" button to each element using SPServices? and then display elements as divs like this:

[image]

Comment: You can do CSR using JSLinks. Basically you handle how the field should get rendered.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you are talking about modifying current list view and rearrange elements to display as I want?

Comment: Yes. You can do what goes where and how it should be displayed etc. In your case I believe you just need to handle how the like field is rendered

Comment: I just need "like" button on square containing image or title and that is it

Answer (score 0):

there's a JS function called set like that can help you, you might want to try to mix CSOm and JSOM to create the functionality you want

you only need 4 parameters 
the clientcontext (which is loaded for the site that contains the list)
the ListId
the ItemID
the Value =True to like/False to unlike

Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(ClientContext,listId,ItemId,Value)

then you can execute your queryasync and switch the label text to like/unlike depending the like status.

you'll still need to query somehow the item's likecount field to check if the users has liked the item before adding the like/unlike button